# Nebular chat component - not scrolling to bottom automatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, chat, chatbot, nebular

I am using Nebular with Angular, specifically the chat UI component. I have mainly used it from default and haven't changed much - however when I test it and add new messages the window doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom. This is obviously quite a bit user experience and I don't know how to change it. Not sure which file to look at as there are so many chat component files but these are my main chatbot files:

chatbot.component.html:

```
<nb-chat title="Conversation with a Bot">

    <nb-chat-message *ngFor="let msg of messages"
                     type="text"
                     [message]="msg.text"
                     [reply]="msg.reply"
                     [sender]="msg.sender"
                     [date]="msg.date"
                     [avatar]="msg.avatar">
    </nb-chat-message>


    <nb-chat-message *ngIf="loading" [nbSpinner]="loading" nbSpinnerStatus="info"
        type="text"
        avatar="/assets/gcp.png"
        message="...">

    </nb-chat-message>


  <nb-chat-form (send)="handleUserMessage($event)"></nb-chat-form>

</nb-chat>
```

Part of my chatbot.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbot',
  templateUrl: './chatbot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbot.component.scss']
})
```

Another part of the chatbot.component.ts

```
  addBotMessage(text) {
    this.messages.push({
      text: text,
      sender: 'Bot',
      avatar: '/assets/gcp.png',
      date: new Date()
    });
  }
```

Also as a bonus does anyone know how to get the time with the date, as it's currently only producing the current date without time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Nebular Component however I see the method addBotMessage which I believe is triggered once the message is coming in. All you need to do is to add window.scroll method to addBotMessage()

```
window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Which works for all common browsers. Scroll to top would be:

```
  window.scroll(0,0)
```

apply for your method:

```
  addBotMessage(text) {
    this.messages.push({
      text: text,
      sender: 'Bot',
      avatar: '/assets/gcp.png',
      date: new Date()
    });
    window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
  }
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thansk so much, this did mostly work however there's a slight gap at the bottom it missed (possibly due to the text entry box) so a bit confused on that. Will continue to try to solve.